# Format function convert "23.6" in "1,0"

Tags: vba

I'm trying to convert a number I get from a file with format function to display it the proper way.

It was working fine since a while until I noticed a weird result I can't explain...

```vb
MyValue="23.6"
debug.Print VBA.Format(MyValue, "##0.0")
```

Here are some examples of what I get :
"68.1" => 68.1 : OK
"23.6" => 1,0 : NOK

I'm working on a french computer.

Comment: Not able to replicate the issue. Prints correctly in my System.

Comment: Do you tkink it's interpreted in the wrong way ?

Comment: @lea I think I solved your issue, Please give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57409890/11167163) a try and give me some feedbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lea,

You need to convert your Value as a `Numeric` Value.

To do this you can use `val()` function

```
Sub test()
  MyValue = "23.6"
  Debug.Print VBA.Format(Val(MyValue), "##0.0")
End Sub
```

Please have a look to the [val()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) documentation.

Comment: Thank you Dorian, it's working perfectly !  I tried CDbl but got an error. Didn't know `val` function

Comment: @lea You are Welcome, I wish you all the best